# Android: Pending intent not calledon snooze with multiple alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

I am working on adding multiple alarm functionality in my existing app. Earlier, the alarm was  single only and every thing worked fine. I have been able to set multiple alarms, it is working fine too, but problem is with snooze feature. Earlier, snooze was working perfect. But, after multiple alarm implementation it is not working. I never get dialog for snoozing alarm, once I press snooze button. Here is my code:

**Set alarm method**

```
public void setAlarm(boolean AlarmEnabled, int AlarmHour, int AlarmMin) {
        //Build Intent/Pending Intent for setting the alarm
        Intent AlarmIntent = new Intent(MultipleAlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        AlarmManager AlmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        int _id = (int)System.currentTimeMillis();
        AlarmIntent.putExtra("REQUEST CODE", _id);
        Log.v("MultipleAlarmActivity RequestCode", ""+_id);
        PendingIntent Sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MultipleAlarmActivity.this, _id, AlarmIntent, 0);     

        //Build Calendar objects for setting alarm
        Calendar curCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar alarmCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        //Initialize Seconds and Milliseconds to 0 for both calendars
        curCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        curCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);           
        alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        //Update alarmCalendar with Alarm Hour and Minute Settings
        alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, AlarmHour);
        alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, AlarmMin);

        //If Alarm Time is now or in the past, set it for tomorrow 24 hours in advance from time selected
        if (alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis() <= curCalendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
            alarmCalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);
        }
        //Set the alarm
        AlmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), Sender);

        //Build the Strings for displaying the alarm time through Toast
        String CalendarHourStr;
        if (AlarmHour > 12) {
            CalendarHourStr = Integer.toString(AlarmHour - 12);
        } else {
            CalendarHourStr = Integer.toString(AlarmHour);
        }
        String CalendarMinStr = Integer.toString(AlarmMin);
        if (AlarmMin < 10) {
            CalendarMinStr = "0" + CalendarMinStr;
        }

        String strAmPM;
        if (AlarmHour < 12) {
            strAmPM = "AM";
        }
        else {
            strAmPM = "PM";
        }
        String alarmTime = Integer.toString(alarmCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + Integer.toString(alarmCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) + "/" + Integer.toString(alarmCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + " " + CalendarHourStr + ":" + CalendarMinStr + " " + strAmPM;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set For " + alarmTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
         Log.v("MultipleAlarmActivity setAlarm", "in if loop");
    Log.v("MultipleAlarmActivity setAlarm", "setAlarm called");
}
```

**Alarm Receiver**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
public static final String ALARM_ALERT_ACTION = "com.android.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT";
public static final String ALARM_INTENT_EXTRA = "intent.extra.alarm";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{ 
    Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    in.setClass(context, SnoozeActivity.class);
    Log.v("AlarmReceiver RequestCode", ""+intent.getIntExtra("REQUEST CODE", 0));
    in.putExtra("REQUEST CODE", intent.getIntExtra("REQUEST CODE", 0));
    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(in);
}
}
```

**Method for snoozing alarm**

```
private void snooze() 
{
        //Set Calendar Value for Snooze Alarm
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        //int snoozeTime = mMinute + SNOOZE_MIN;
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, SNOOZE_MIN); //SNOOZE_MIN = 1;
        long snoozeTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        //Build Intent and Pending Intent to Set Snooze Alarm               
        Intent AlarmIntent = new Intent(SnoozeActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        AlarmManager AlmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        AlarmIntent.putExtra("REQUEST CODE", req_code);
        PendingIntent Sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SnoozeActivity.this, req_code, AlarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);   
        AlmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, snoozeTime, Sender);
        timer.cancel();   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem. I was using a boolean value for checking whether alarm has been set or not. And, I forgot to set this value as true when I called setAlarm(). Thats my mistake.