# Alarm stop's when snoozed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alarms

This is the alarm activity, on alarm set Two CAncel and Snooze, Default snooze kept as 4 Seconds, This is working fine when we kept alarm, but when click snooze it alarm stops unfortunately on snoozed time.

```
public class AlarmAlertActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener        {

private Calendar alarmTime = Calendar.getInstance();
final Context context = this;
private Alarm alarm;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private Vibrator vibrator;
private boolean alarmActive;
private TextView msg_txt, alarmname_txt;
private ImageView img1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.simple);

    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    alarm = (Alarm) bundle.getSerializable("alarm");
    Button can1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.can1);
    Button snoozebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.snoozebtn);

    Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shake);
    Animation shakeimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shakeimage);
    msg_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg_txt);
    alarmname_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmname_txt);
    img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.smileyblack);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    hr1 = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); 
    startAlarm();

    can1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });

    snoozebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
    snoozeAlarm(4, ((AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE)), context);
            finish();
        }
    });
    }

private void startAlarm() {
    if (alarm.getAlarmTonePath() != "") {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        if (alarm.getVibrate()) {
            vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            long[] pattern = { 1000, 200, 200, 200 };
            vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);
        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this,
                    Uri.parse(alarm.getAlarmTonePath()));
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            alarmActive = false;
        }
    }

}

public static final void snoozeAlarm(int seconds, AlarmManager alarmManager,
        Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmAlertActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + seconds * 1000, pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Snoozed to " + seconds + " seconds.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} }
```

/* This is the Alarm Class

```
  public class Alarm implements Serializable {
public String toString() {
        switch(this.ordinal()){
            case 0:
                return "Sunday";
            case 1:
                return "Monday";
            case 2:
                return "Tuesday";
            case 3:
                return "Wednesday";
            case 4:
                return "Thursday";
            case 5:
                return "Friay";
            case 6:
                return "Saturday";
        }
        return super.toString();
    }

}
private int id;
private Boolean alarmActive = true;
private Calendar alarmTime = Calendar.getInstance();
private Day[] days = {Day.MONDAY,Day.TUESDAY,Day.WEDNESDAY,Day.THURSDAY,Day.FRIDAY,Day.SATURDAY,Day.SUNDAY};    
private String alarmTonePath = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM).toString();
private Boolean vibrate = true;
private String alarmName = "Alarm";

public Alarm() {

}


public Boolean getAlarmActive() {
    return alarmActive;
}

public void setAlarmActive(Boolean alarmActive) {
    this.alarmActive = alarmActive;
}

public Calendar getAlarmTime() {
    if (alarmTime.before(Calendar.getInstance()))
        alarmTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    while(!Arrays.asList(getDays()).contains(Day.values()[alarmTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1])){
        alarmTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);            
    }
    return alarmTime;
}

public String getAlarmTimeString() {
    String time = "";
    if (alarmTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) <= 9)
        time += "0";
    time += String.valueOf(alarmTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    time += ":";

    if (alarmTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) <= 9)
        time += "0";
    time += String.valueOf(alarmTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

    return time;
}

public void setAlarmTime(Calendar alarmTime) {
    this.alarmTime = alarmTime;
}

public void setAlarmTime(String alarmTime) {
    String[] timePieces = alarmTime.split(":");
    Calendar newAlarmTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    newAlarmTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,
            Integer.parseInt(timePieces[0]));
    newAlarmTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(timePieces[1]));
    newAlarmTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    setAlarmTime(newAlarmTime);     
}

public Day[] getDays() {
    return days;
}

public void setDays(Day[] days) {
    this.days = days;
}

public void addDay(Day day){
    boolean contains = false;


}

public void removeDay(Day day) {

    List<Day> result = new LinkedList<Day>();
    for(Day d : getDays())
        if(!d.equals(day))
            result.add(d);
    setDays(result.toArray(new Day[result.size()]));
}

public String getAlarmTonePath() {
    return alarmTonePath;
}

public void setAlarmTonePath(String alarmTonePath) {
    this.alarmTonePath = alarmTonePath;
}

public String getAlarmName() {
    return alarmName;
}

public void setAlarmName(String alarmName) {
    this.alarmName = alarmName;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public void schedule(Context context) {
    setAlarmActive(true);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("alarm", this);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getAlarmTime().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);                 
}

public String getTimeUntilNextAlarmMessage(){

        }
    }
    return alert;
}
```

}

Alarm is working fine, but when i set snoozed for 4 sec , Unfortunately stops when snoozed

This is the Error in LOGCAT

```
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.am.alarm/com.am.alarm.alert.AlarmAlertActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at com.am.alarm.alert.AlarmAlertActivity.startAlarm(AlarmAlertActivity.java:178)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at com.am.alarm.alert.AlarmAlertActivity.onCreate(AlarmAlertActivity.java:92)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
   04-24 13:42:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465609/android-pending-intent-not-calledon-snooze-with-multiple-alarm  This link may be helps you to snooze the Alarm.

Comment: My educated guess is that you are using the same ID for the alarm and for the snoozed alarm which overrides the previous alarm. 
I hope that solves your issue..

Comment: I think Your alarmManager is null, try to initialize it like that: AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(mContext.ALARM_SERVICE);

Comment: @DeJaVo Changed the id  "0" to "1" for the snooze alarm. still the same problem

Comment: If it´s not the alarmManager, it only could be the context. Initialize Your snooze() method like this: snoozeAlarm(4, mAlarmManager, AlarmAlertActivity.this); <-- use AlarmAlertActivity.this instead of Your context.

Comment: yes, but if context is null ,every use of context will throw this exception. Change every "contex" inside Your snooze() method to AlarmAlertActivity.this....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs can we use AlarmAlertActivity.this  in a static context ?

Comment: what is in line 178 ?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs   if (alarm.getAlarmTonePath() != "") , starting line of startalarm().

Comment: so You should provide Your getAlarmTonePath method from Your Alarm class....and if You compare strings it must be equals() --> eg if(!alarm.getAlarmTonePath().equals("")

Comment: and better post Your Alarm class complete if it is not too large..we need to see how do You pass Your serializable..

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Posted alarm class

Comment: I think the problem is a little bit difficult. I assume that the serializable is null, so Your alarm is also null. So, I hope we get it now, we need to see how do You start the AlarmAlertActivity for the first time, before You snooze the alarm. The important thing is, show us how You start this activity the first time and how You are passing Your serializable...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs   Intent AlarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmServiceBroadcastReciever.class)
  sendBroadcast(AlarmIntent, null), in the AlarmServiceBroadcastReciever.class starting an activity  AlarmAlertActivity.class

Comment: please post this Receiver, and passing the serializable and post how do You start the Alarm the first time (complete)

Comment: Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever.class);
myIntent.putExtra("alarm", this);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getAlarmTime().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent); from the broadcast started service and from the service this is the first time to start alarm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue , instead of calling activity directly from intent, passed Broadcast reciever then activity in Broadcast reciever.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, BroadcastReciever.class);
    intent.putExtra("alarm", alarm);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1 , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its due to the finish() call you have provided.